# Check for interchangable column values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables. The first one contains IDs of certain airports, the second contains flights from one airport to another.

```
ID   Airport 
---- ----
12  NYC
23  LOS
21  AMS
54  SFR
33  LSA

from  to   cost
---- ----  ----
12  23     500
12  23     250
23  12     200
21  23     100
54  12     400
33  21     700
```

I'd like to return a table where it contains ONLY airports that are interchangeable (NYC -LOS) in that case, with a total cost.
please note that there're identical (from , to) rows with different costs and the desired output needs to aggregate all costs for each unique combination

Desired Output :

```
airport_1  airport_2   total_cost
----         ----        ----
 NYC         LOS         950
```

Comment: How do you determine which is airport1 and which is airport2?

Comment: cause it had a smaller id , but it doesn't matter which is the airport1 & airport2

Comment: sorry about that , but I didn't change the criteria , I just made it more clear and some answers already filled the criteria, the problem is that I see a discrepancy that's why I still didn't choose any answers

Comment: you should not edit a question and change its criteria after people have put the effort in to provide an answer, this invalidates your question and is frowned upon. Having said that, the answer I posted earlier still provides the desired results. Ideally though if this is not suitable you should ask a new question.

Comment: that's true , your query does EXACTLY what I want .However, since I see a discrepancy in results between other answers like what @Barbaros Özhan  posted , I don't know which is the right result !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result without need of a subquery by using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` functions along with `HAVING` clause such as

```sql
 SELECT MIN(airport) AS airport_1, MAX(airport) AS airport_2, SUM(cost)/2 AS total_cost
   FROM flights
   JOIN airports
     ON id IN ("from" , "to")
   GROUP BY LEAST("from","to"), GREATEST("from","to")
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "from")*COUNT(DISTINCT "to")=4
```

where each pair(**2**) is counted twice(**2**) -> (**2*****2**=**4**)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6a671050fdb5b713cdbc01deb563837)</kbd>

Comment: would that work if I have more than one (from , to) identical rows with different costs ?
and could you please explain why we divide sum(cost)  / 2 ?

Comment: good catch @koko99 , then need a slight change. For (**/2**), we summing up totals twice as I already mentioned in the tail part of the answer.

Comment: sorry but I still can't get my head around the division of the sum , what I understand is that after the group by I'll have like NYC_LOS pair with a cost of 400 , and another LOS_NYC with a different cost like 500 , shouldn't I just sum both of the costs without the division ??

Comment: Hi @koko99 the confusion stems from the matching the tables twice by using two matched columns from the flights table. eg. `id IN ("from" , "to")` . It generates a cross join impact, and the rows are duplicated. eg. we're counting twice for each individual match. Btw, consider as another option that you can join as twice much as flight table with  `"from"` for once, and `"to"` for the other individually. You can check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=aa5c59f487d5dd03690ed9f5c0ade5a9) out.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to do all the explanations. I get it now